# Align icon and Heading adjacent to each other in Text View (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview, drawable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0ExQ.png)I have to align the clock icon at the top left and after a few padding display the corresponding heading, I have tried using drawableStart but it show the icon in middle left, Please can you suggest to me the changes that I should made in the current code
.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="199dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_white"
    android:text="Counsel overview"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_clock"

    android:padding="20dp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    >

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_white"
    android:text="Pricing chart"

    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_clock"
    android:padding="20dp" />
```